# Is there a converter between django.forms.Form and rest_framework.serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I already have plenty of forms defined in my django 1.9 project. Now I need to export them as REST (DRF 3.5.3) as well.

With just a bit of hacking, I was able to provide GET and PUT methods. But I also need to provide the OPTIONS method and I can't seem to find anything that would help me do that.

So, is there something that would convert an instanced form to DRF Serializer / ViewSet?

Answer (score 3):

No but you can do the other way around as explained in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms.

Answer (score 0):

`drf-braces` can do this.

from django import forms
from drf_braces.serializers.form_serializer import FormSerializer

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    bar = forms.DateTimeField()

class MySerializer(FormSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        form = MyForm
```

https://github.com/dealertrack/django-rest-framework-braces/blob/master/docs/overview.rst

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - and it seems to do exactly what I needed back then. But I have since completely abandoned Django forms and just moved to DRF altogether.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want to mess with all of my custom logic in the forms, so I just added an `as_options` method:

```
class APIViewForm(Form):

    def as_dict(self):
        return {fld.auto_id: self.initial.get(fld.name, None) for fld in self}

    def as_options(self):
        flds = {}
        for fld in self:
            flds[fld.name] = f = {}
            fld = fld.field
            f.update(dict(
                required=fld.required,
                read_only=fld.disabled,
                label=fld.label,
            ))
            if isinstance(fld, (CharField, URLField)):
                f['type'] = 'field'
                if fld.max_length:
                    f['max_length'] = fld.max_length
                if fld.min_length:
                    f['min_length'] = fld.min_length
            elif isinstance(fld, IntegerField):
                f['type'] = 'integer'
                if fld.max_value:
                    f['max_value'] = fld.max_value
                if fld.min_value:
                    f['min_value'] = fld.min_value
            elif isinstance(fld, ChoiceField):
                f['type'] = 'choice'
                f['choices'] = [dict(value=c[0], display_name=c[1]) for c in fld.choices]
            elif isinstance(fld, DateTimeField):
                f['type'] = 'datetime'

        return dict(
            name=self.__class__.__qualname__,
            description='',
            renders=['application/json'],
            parses=['application/json'],
            actions=dict(PUT=flds)
        )
```

It seems to do the trick